# console.log is not a function Firefox 3.6.16

Tags: firefox, console

Is this a bug? It was working fine until I upgraded this morning. Console is enabled, is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 6):

I think `console.log()` is part of Firebug.

Did you upgrade Firebug alongside Firefox?

Comment: I'm using 1.6.2, which I just uploaded but I think that was the version I was using.

Comment: : D Not stupid at all, yes, it is and console is enabled. Computer is plugged in as well. : D (I work with help desk folks so yeah, sometimes you got to climb the ladder for some people - plugged in, monitor on, etc. etc.) : D

Comment: Interesting link provided by The Google: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/planet-mozilla/how-to-debug-firebug/

Comment: (I spent 20 minutes last week on the phone with a friend debugging a sound problem. Guess who didn't have their speakers turned on?) Have you tried Firefox 4? I'm not a FF user, so I can't do much, but maybe if you posted some contextual code, I could see if it's something with the code?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error report with Firebug running.

I was calling console.log inside a jquery extension - changing the call to

```
window.console.log('foo');
```

gave it the right context and it started working.

Might help to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Exactly as Blender suggested.

**Upgrade Firebug to the latest.**

..and maybe restart the browser. I did out of habit.

I had the exact same issue this morning.